# AngularJS: Compiling an element with another directive changes behavior

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am seeing inconsistent behavior with a directive when I $compile the element that contains the directive.  In my case I have a directive that validates whether a password matches another password field.  That directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('passwordMatches', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        otherPasswordFieldValue: '=passwordMatches'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {
        function validate(value) {
            return value === scope.otherPasswordFieldValue;
        }

        //For DOM -> model validation
        ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            var valid = validate(value);
            ngModelController.$setValidity('password-matches', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        //For model -> DOM validation
        ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
            ngModelController.$setValidity('password-matches', validate(value));
            return value;
        });

        scope.$watch(function() { return scope.otherPasswordFieldValue }, function () {
            var valid = validate(ngModelController.$viewValue);
            ngModelController.$setValidity('password-matches', valid);
        });
      }
    };
});
```

This works fine alone.  But I have another directive that is often used on the same element.  The details of that directive aren't important because I've shown that **the root cause of the issue is that that second directive compiles the element**.  As soon as I add this directive, the behavior changes.  Without compiling the element, my passwordMatches directive works fine (the field becomes invalid if what I type doesn't match the other field and I can type whatever I want).

But **as soon as I compile the element**, I can type what I want until I make the fields match and it behaves normally up until that point.  But once the values in the two fields match, if I type anything to make them not match, the field is completely blanked out.  The easiest way to see this is in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/IkuMECEf/12/edit.  To reproduce, type "foo" in the first field and then try to type "fooo" (three o's) in the second field.  As soon as you type the third "o" the field is blanked out.  If you comment out the $compile, it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: what is purpose of `$compile` in second directive? Is only being run on `input` currently and don't see anything that needs compiling in demo

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to complicate the demo with those details.  It is another directive that adds a validation related ng-class to the element.  I need a directive to do this because the ng-class content is dynamic based on the type of validation being performed. Since it's adding an angular directive, it needs to compile the element again.

Comment: perhaps could use a function that returns the class? `ng-class="vaildationClass()"`.

Comment: also likely want to play with `priority`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, charlietfl.   I did try changing the priority and that didn't change anything.  I would rather not have to put the ng-class attribute in the html (calling a method) and let the existing directives handle that to make coding the html more simple, but maybe that is what I will have to resort to.

Answer (score 0):

The second directive is compiling dom elements that have already been compiled by Angular. This second compile adds a second `$watch`, parser, etc because all the directive's linking functions are called again ([here's a good detailed look at $compile](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html))  To confirm this you can put a `console.log` inside the `$watch` and you'll see that (with the second directive) it fires twice for every change- because of the duplicate `$watch` (remove the second directive and it fires only once- as expected).  This second compilation step is not only causing the issue you're seeing but could cause other problems down the line.

If you have to recompile an Angular element then you first need to remove the existing one.

Here's one approach to this (explanation in the comments):

```
compile: function(compileElement) {
  compileElement.removeAttr('another-directive');
  return function(scope, element) {

    // Create an "uncompiled" element using a copy of the current element's html 
    newe = angular.element(element.html());

    // Remember where we were
    parent= element.parent();

    // Deleting the current "compiled" element
    element.remove();

    // Add the uncompiled copy
    parent.append(news);

    // Compile the copy
    $compile(newe)(scope);   
  };
```

[updated punker](http://jsbin.com/IkuMECEf/20/edit)

Comment: moves element outside parent...simpler `element.after(newe);       element.remove();`

Comment: @charliefl good point.  There will very briefly be both elements on the dom- but that should be so brief that it doesn't have any real world implications.

Comment: wondering about that myself...could wrap span maybe then unwrap span after

Comment: @charlietfl  I updated it.  Instead of using clone, just grabbing the html, turning that into a new element and then appending it (instead of using `.after()` cleans it up.  Good catch!

Comment: I am going to try this solution, but I'm curious if anyone has an idea  why this happens in the first place.  Almost seems like an Angular bug, but could be a misunderstanding.

Comment: It's happening because compile asks Angular to run all directives link functions, etc..  needed to make that piece of the dom angular ready. Angular doesn't check to see that the dom has already been compiled- it just runs another compile- so link runs again, etc.  Angular could protect against this but that would add performance overhead.  Since Angular considers compile to be something that most people don't need to run directly I can definitely see the logic of erring on the side of performance here.  So I wouldn't say a bug as much as a design tradeoff.